# Unable to utilize the :not CSS selector around SVGs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, css-selectors

I'm wrapping some SVG icons in a div element and try to have icons with a certain CSS class show, while hiding all others. I'm also trying to utilize the :not selector in all this, which works fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox (48.0.2).

The following should display both text and icon in Chrome and Safari, but displays only the text in Firefox:

```
    <style>
        div:not(.foo) svg       { display: none; }
        div:not(.foo) svg.bork  { display: block; }
        div:not(.foo) span      { display: none; }
        div:not(.foo) span.bork { display: block; }
    </style>

    <svg display="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <symbol id="icon">
            <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/" d="M4.478,26.134,35.037,56.693,4.478,87.252a15.313,15.313,0,1,0,21.656,21.656L56.693,78.349l30.559,30.559a15.313,15.313,0,0,0,21.656-21.656L78.349,56.693l30.559-30.559A15.313,15.313,0,0,0,87.252,4.478L56.693,35.037,26.134,4.478A15.313,15.313,0,0,0,4.478,26.134Zm19.86-19.86L46.452,28.388,54.9,36.833l1.8,1.8,1.8-1.8L66.319,29,89.048,6.274a12.773,12.773,0,0,1,18.064,18.064L84.383,47.067l-7.83,7.83-1.8,1.8,1.8,1.8,5.317,5.317,25.242,25.242a12.773,12.773,0,0,1-18.064,18.064L63.806,81.87l-5.317-5.317-1.8-1.8-1.8,1.8-6.562,6.562-24,24A12.773,12.773,0,1,1,6.274,89.048l24-24,6.562-6.562,1.8-1.8-1.8-1.8-8.445-8.445L6.274,24.338A12.773,12.773,0,0,1,24.338,6.274Z"></path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>

    <div class="bar">
        <span>This text should not be displayed</span>
        <span class="bork">This text should be displayed</span>
        <svg class="bork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/">
            <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/jfvaren/pen/wzoxEG

I included that span element to show that the problem only affects the svg element. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866893/svg-fill-not-being-applied-in-firefox

Comment: @Robert Longson: I agree that the cause of the symptom has been explained in said article, but calling it a duplicate seems a bit far-stretched.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen here? We post the same or similar anwers to this question as exist on the other one? How does that improve things?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd like a short explanation of why this happens, a link to a bug report or article and preferably the one-liner CSS that circumvents the bug in the example I provided. The cause of the symptoms is the same, yes, but the symptoms and questions are not. The example code given in the so-called duplicate question is also very specific and incomplete, making the answer harder to fit into this context. It did help me solve my problem in the end, but it was a time consuming detour that could have been avoided with a straight answer. Redundancy isn't always a bad thing ;-)

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265894 (This link was already present in a comment to the accepted answer and I've added it into the accepted answer as well).