# Trouble with svg in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have svg in my web site which works fine in chrome but when I try to check it on Firefox the thing is out of frame enlarged I think. I am a designer who started coding few months back. Here is the image for chrome and Firefox.

In Chrome:

[image: in Chrome this is how it looks]

In Firefox:

[image: in firefox it looks like this]

Here is the code snippet i used

```css
svg {
    display: block;
    font: 10.5em 'Arial';
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-copy {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
    animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(1){
    stroke: #4D163D;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(2){
    stroke: #840037;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(3){
    stroke: #BD0034;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(4){
    stroke: #BD0034;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(5){
    stroke: #FDB731;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
@keyframes stroke-offset{
    100% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    svg{
        width: 750px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    svg{
        font: 6.5em 'Arial';
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .text-copy {
        fill: none;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
        animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
    }
}

.text-center1{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px ;
  margin-top:40px;
}
@media (max-width:992px){
  .text-centre1{
    font-size:30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <symbol id="s-text">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">Digital</text>
    </symbol>
    <g class = "g-ants">
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your svg seems pretty “naked” - no viewbox defined, no width/height attributes either ... Check https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/, it covers the basics of what attributes you should have set to get this working properly.

Comment: While that is reasonable advice, those issues aren't the cause of OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Firefox.

If you apply an `em`-based font size to the `<svg>` and have text inside a `<symbol>` then in Firefox, the `<text>` element thinks the font should be 10.5 times the current font size of 10.5em.  In other words the font size is multiplying and ends up as 110.25em.

The simple solution is to move the `font` rule to the `<text>` ekement.

```
text {
  font: 10.5em 'Arial';
}
```

```css
svg {
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

text {
    font: 10.5em 'Arial';
}

.text-copy {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
    animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(1){
    stroke: #4D163D;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(2){
    stroke: #840037;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(3){
    stroke: #BD0034;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(4){
    stroke: #BD0034;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(5){
    stroke: #FDB731;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
@keyframes stroke-offset{
    100% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    svg{
        width: 750px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    svg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    text {
        font: 6.5em 'Arial';
    }
    .text-copy {
        fill: none;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
        animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
    }
}

.text-center1{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px ;
  margin-top:40px;
}
@media (max-width:992px){
  .text-centre1{
    font-size:30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <symbol id="s-text">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">Digital</text>
    </symbol>
    <g class = "g-ants">
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I have reported the bug to Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1392619

Comment: It was fixed a while ago, the fix is in Firefox 56, or you can try the [beta right now](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/).

Comment: Thanks Robert. I wasn't aware of that one. @Seemant See also the following answer for more information on this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866893/svg-fill-not-being-applied-in-firefox/27872310#27872310

Comment: Thanks @Paul LeBeau

Answer (score -2):

As a rule of thumb, always include `height`,`width` and `viewBox` for svg images as attributes as opposed to CSS style. Different browsers render SVG differently if these attributes are not present.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? If you miss the above attributes in a svg element, the graphic is displayed differently in different browsers.