# svg fill is not working in Firefox

Tags: css, html, svg, jquery-svg

I am trying to give fill to my svg and everything is working fine in chrome and IE but not in Firefox. In Firefox I can see the style while inspecting but it does not get the color. If I try to keep only path without social-link class in css then it works but I want it with parent class like .social-link path.
Thank you in advance.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });
 })
```

```css
.social-link path {
    fill: #ee44ff;
}
```

```html
<img id="facebook-logo" class="svg social-link" src="images/facebook.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing svg via img tag. Can you please open SVG image in any editor, Copy the code and paste it in your html. Then add class to path and apply css. It will solve your problem. *NOTE* In code, Make sure to check that path don't have attribute like fill="none". If yes than remove it.

Comment: It won't if the svg image is maintained by a third party or if in production code the refeence is dynamic.

Comment: There is no fill="none". Its working on Chrome and IE. Even in firefox you can see the style while inspecting but the color is not getting changed.

Comment: Please create fiddle or pen for the same.

Comment: path.fb-path{ fill:#ee44ff; } - Use this css, Thats it!

Comment: I actually wanted it to get selected with parent selector like svg path.fb-path

Comment: Because I am tyring to append .svg file on the img tag as you can see it above and there will be multiple .svg file so a parent selector will be great. Thank you.

Comment: Css will look like svg.social-link path.fb-path{ fill:#ee44ff; }

Comment: @GopalGarva Please have a look.Thank you.

Comment: In that case please check this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866893/svg-fill-not-being-applied-in-firefox

Comment: Hey it is working if I select <g> tag instead of <path> to give css. Is it a right way to give css to <g> tag as this is my first time with svg.

Comment: Yes you can apply css on g tag if it is working for you.