# SVGs with use xlink not working in Firefox 84

Tags: svg, firefox, cross-browser

I'm having an issue where I have a couple of SVGs that are not showing up in Firefox. They work fine in Chromium and Safari.

HTML

```
<svg
  class="something">
  <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#home" />
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.something {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    fill: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Sprite.svg

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M28 17.333v13.333h-8v-8h-8v8h-8v-13.333h-4l16-16 16 16h-4zM26.667 9.457v-6.791h-4v2.791l4 4z"></path>
</symbol>
...
</defs>
</svg>
```

Upon inspection with developer tools, I can see the path for Chrome:

[image]

But not for Firefox:

[image]

What I have already tried based on other posts:

- Made sure xmlns is declared, as well as width and height
- Adding fill inherit to svg use svg (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124867/2910611)
- Made sure there are no commas in the d attribute of path
- Playing with fill="currentColor" to see if it was instead a problem of fill
- Using href instead of xlink:href

Any idea how to resolve this?

I see from [caniuse that Firefox supports use xlink:href](https://caniuse.com/mdn-svg_elements_use_xlink_href).

It seems to be a problem of rendering and not fill as changing the size of the icon isn't causing visible changes.

Comment: Yes it's a web server. Even deployed isn't working. Sprites.svg is at root and I have confirmed the request to get it is returning 200.

Comment: I already found out the issue. In the sprites file one of the symbols didn't have a closing tag. For some reason other browsers were still able to display all of them, but not FF so I didn't notice the problem until now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: one of the symbols in the sprites file didn't have a closing tag. For some reason other browsers were still able to display all of them without complaining, but not Firefox.

Since it may happen to others, I'll keep the question posted.

Comment: Browsers shouldn't use invalid XML but they also do incremental rendering so in a large sprite sheet they may not have found the syntax error before they use the icon.

Comment: @RobertLongson the surprising thing here is that it wasn't even the last symbol, so Chromium was able to display the last one, even if along the way there's a syntax error, while FF simply didn't show any

Comment: Well that would seem to be a Chrome bug then because as far as I can see that's not valid behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, i missed a defs closing tag , that's where the error originated from.

Comment: Your answer is basically covered by the answer Mondego provided.

Comment: it's not the same, mine was lacking a defs closing tag and not a symbol closing tag...

Comment: Yes, the cases are not the same. But the "missing closing tag" idea was there already. Hence the "basically".
While suggesting alternatives is encouraged, especially where the question asks for "any ideas", your very specific suggestion is unlikely to help anyone. Unless you offer The Solution to the question, keep it more general - a comment "Remember to check other tags as well." on Mondego's answer would have been fair.
Also, "that's where the error originated from" no longer relates to this question.
Do not be discouraged, just aim for better answers. We help each other.